# How do I get this Nokogiri output to write each object to a column in a csv?

Tags: ruby

I have this code here which outputs a CSV, but when I open the CSV file its just has a 0 in the first two columns.

```
require 'rubygems'
 require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'


page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.drugs.com/pharmaceutical-
companies.html"))
puts page.class #=> Nokogiri::HTML::Document


pharma_links = page.css("div.col-list-az a")

link= pharma_links.each{|link| puts link['href'] }
company = pharma_links.each{|link| puts link.text} 



CSV.open("/Users/file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << [company, link]
end
```

Comment: See, told ya :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `pharma_links.each{|link| ...}` returns the ENTIRE enumerator, so if you do this once for `company` and once for `link` you now have two new arrays. You then have to re-map each company & link in a new array / hash (or by index if you are lazy AND you know for certain nothing went wrong in the either `.each` call)

To avoid this, simply construct the CSV while you are looping through the data. *For each line of the `CSV` you expect one `pharma_links` 'line'*, so iterate through each at the same time:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'


page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.drugs.com/pharmaceutical-companies.html"))
# puts page.class #=> Nokogiri::HTML::Document


pharma_links = page.css("div.col-list-az a")

# Create the CSV and iterate through the links while creating it
# You can also add headers to the CSV on instantiation
CSV.open("file.csv", "wb", write_headers: true, headers: ['url','description']) do |csv| 
  pharma_links.each do |link|
    puts "Adding #{link.text}" # prove that it works :)
    csv << [link['href'], link.text]
  end
end
```

Comment: you sir are an angel sent from god

Comment: `map` is misused here.

Comment: What Sergio said, you should use `each` if you aren't intending to use the returned enumerator from map.

Comment: Updated the post